# Coping buffer using memcpy results to output 0?

Tags: c++

I have tried to simplify the original code to a simple test example which replicates the issue that I am having. I do apologize for the simple question in advance.. I am a beginner with C++.

So moving on the actual question.. why do I get 0 as an output? For the purposes of my this example and for my understanding, functions should not be modified with the exception of the numerical values in them should it be required (meaning I got it wrong:).

Many thanks in advance.

```
static unsigned short buffer[5];

void settingMemory()
{
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
}

void copingMemory(const unsigned short *pixels)
{
    memcpy(&buffer[5], pixels, 5*sizeof(unsigned short));
}

void printingMemory()
{
    unsigned short *test = buffer;
    std::cout << *test << std::endl;
    std::cout << *test++ << std::endl;
    std::cout << *test++ << std::endl;
    std::cout << *test++ << std::endl;
    std::cout << *test++ << std::endl;
    std::cout << *test++ << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    settingMemory();
    unsigned short test[5];
    test[0] = 5;
    test[1] = 55;
    test[2] = 555;
    test[3] = 5555;
    test[4] = 55555;
    copingMemory(test);
    printingMemory();
}
```

My output is:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: You're copying and printing off the end of the passed in array.

Comment: Use std::vector. If you really need to copy, use std::copy instead of memcopy. What do you think `&buffer[5]` is?

Comment: Thank you Michael for the quick response.

For my understanding, would it be possible to give me a working example?

Comment: @user3270371 You probably want to copy into the start of the array, for that, just use `memcpy(buffer, pixels,...)` and your `settingMemory` isn't doing what you think it is (hint: don't use the same name for a global and a local variable).

Comment: @MichaelAlbers I have corrected the settingMemory function. Oups!

Comment: Thank you everyone! I got it working per your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `memcpy(&buffer[5], pixels, 5*sizeof(unsigned short));` copies to the start of the **6th** element of buffer (i.e. the first element /outside/ the buffer. Replace it with `memcpy(&buffer[0], pixels, 5*sizeof(unsigned short));`, so you copy it to the **1st** element instead.